# Role of the weight matrix $M$ in $x^T M u$ in the LQR cost function

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I wonder what the role of the weight matrix $M$ is in the performance index

$$J = \int_0^{t_f}{\left( x^T Q x + u^T R u + x^T M u \right) \mathrm d t}$$

for an optimal control problem where $$\dot x=Ax+Bu$$ where $u$ is the design variable. Specifically, I mean the *qualitative* effect of such a weight matrix in the resulting controlled problem. How does it affect the performance of the controller and the stability of the closed-loop system?

Comment: So far, I didn't see such a performance index in any textbook/reference; where did you find it?

Comment: For example you can refer to MATLAB help to see this performance index; have not seen it in text books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this performance index is used when, in addition to minimizing the states and the control signal (represented in the terms $x^TQx$ and $u^TRu$), one is also interested in minimizing some output signal
$$
y = Cx + Du.$$
for safety or hard constraints for example (or tracking an output--- this depends on the nature of the used model).

In this case, expanding the weighted norm $y^TNy$, for some positive definite matrix $N$, usually results in cross terms between $x$ and $u$ (which is represented by $x^TMu$).

You can look at this situation as follows: we are not interested only in minimizing a norm of the state and a norm of the inputs, individually, for the usual known reasons, but also we are interested in minimizing linear functions of both $x$ and $u$. In this case you may write the performance index in terms of a single term
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x^T& u^T  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Q & \frac{1}{2}M\\ \frac{1}{2}M^T & R  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\ u  \end{bmatrix}.$$
In otherwords, we work with a concatinated vector $ z:=\begin{bmatrix}x\\ u  \end{bmatrix}$, and we are interested in minimizing a weighted norm$\|z\|_S$.

In the stochastic case, this will correspond to minimizing the error variance in the output signal. Note that the output signal does not have to be given as a state (because states in many models are not even physical and they cannot be measured)

Comment: Very interesting answer. Many thanks. I think the lower left $M$ in the augmented matrix should be transposed but still, your description seems correct if we modify the performance index so that it contains the transposed terms.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I edited my answer accordingly.